# Objects moving very fast in unity2d game when built and ran as a .exe

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the game I have a sprite moving between two points that are `Transform`s.

When in the editor, the sprite moves between the points normally and at a constant, slow speed.

However when I build the game into an `.exe` file and run it, the sprite moves very fast between the two points.

Here is the relevant code for the sprite controller:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MonsterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform pointOne;
    public Transform pointTwo;
    public float speed;
    private bool pointA;
    private bool goingRight;
    private Animator anim;
    public string animLeft;
    public string animRight;

    void Start()
    {
        pointA = true;
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (pointA)
        {
            if (transform.position == pointOne.transform.position)
            {
                pointA = false;
            }
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, pointOne.position, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;);
            goingRight = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (transform.position == pointTwo.transform.position)
            {
                pointA = true;
            }
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, pointTwo.position, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            goingRight = false;
        }

        if (goingRight)
        {
            anim.Play(animRight);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.Play(animLeft);
        }
    }
}
```

As is apparent, if the sprite reaches the point, it will then move to the other point using `Vector2.MoveTowards()`. Any advice and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: within the Update function you should be using Time.deltaTime. if you must use fixedDeltaTime, it should be in a FixedUpdate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments you should either use

[FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) or [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html).

---

- [Update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) is called **every frame**
- [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) is called in a defined realtime interval (by default usually `0.02 seconds`)

The according `Time` values are

- [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html): The realtime passed since the last rendered frame
- [Time.fixedDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html): The realtime interval in which physics methods and e.g. `FixedUpdate` are called (as said by default `0.02 seconds` or `50` times per second)

So as soon as your appliction runs with a framerate `> 50` you get a bigger value from `Time.fixedDeltaTime` (= `0.02`) than from `Time.deltaTime` (e.g. for 60 fps `= 0.017`)

---

Therefore using `Time.fixedDeltaTime` within the `Update` method may result in way bigger values/movements than expected if the framrate is very fast. Within the editor the framerate is slower than in a build because in the build app you get rid of all the UnityEditor overhead.

---

so it should rather be (also simplyfied your `if-else` a bit using the inline [`?`-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) for better readability)

```
private void Update()
{
    var targetPosition = pointA ? pointOne.position : pointTwo.position;

    if (transform.position == targetPosition)
    {
        // invert pointA
        pointA = !pointA;
        // also update the targetPosition
        targetPosition = pointA ? pointOne.position : pointTwo.position;
    }

    // move towards the target using Time.deltaTime
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    // actually you could get rid of this flag as well
    // since it always has the same value as pointA
    goingRight = pointA;

    anim.Play(goingRight ? animRight : animLeft);
}
```